# Sequence is bounded <=> lies in a compact subset?

Tags: real-analysis

In a book I'm reading, there's some theorems that prove some stuff about sequences that lie in compact subsets of some set $S$. Then, in a later theorem, we're asked to assume boundedness about some sequence. What I'm wondering is: if a sequence is bounded, does it always lie in some compact subset (assuming continuity and other required niceties)? Since the book switches between wording, I guess it's not true, but I'm having a hard time concocting a counter-example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $\Bbb R$ endowed with the following distance $d(x,y):=\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$, then $\Bbb N$ is a bounded sequence, however it clearly does not belong to any compact set.

Comment: But in this case, isn't the closure of $\mathbb N$ a compact set?

Comment: @5xum the metric transformation above leaves the topology unchanged, so closure of $\Bbb N$ in $\Bbb R$ with this new metric is still $\Bbb N$

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by the sequence being bounded.  If you mean a real number sequence where the metric is the normal euclidean metric, yes.  Assume all the terms $|a_n|\le M$,  for some $M>0$,  then $a_n\in [-M,M]$,  which is compact.   If you mean bounded in some other metric,  then not necessarily,  as listed by Ilya.

Comment: Wish I could upvote :)

Comment: @luegofuego: now you can :)

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that one direction of the if and only if is true.  That is, if a sequence $\{a_n\}$ lies in a compact subset $Y$, then $\{a_n\}$ is bounded.

Why?  If $Y$ is compact, then $Y$ is bounded.  To prove this, choose any point $x \in X$ and consider the open cover $C = \{N_r(x) : r \in \mathbb{N}\}$.  Since $Y$ is compact, then $C$ admits a finite open subcover for $Y$.  And so...